# How to group similar groups by colum in pandas

Tags: pandas

folks!

I have dataframe like this:

```
ID | Name | Thing | belongs
---+------+---------+--------
 1   John     10       1
 2   Tom      10       2
 3   Tom      10       1
 4   John     10       2
 5   Bob      10       3
```

I can't figure out how to group it like:

```
Tom,John    10  1,2
Bob.        10   3
```

I can groupby them by user, but ill get two groups instead of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'Name': {0: 'John', 1: 'Tom', 2: 'Tom', 3: 'John', 4: 'Bob'},
 'Thing': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10},
 'belongs': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3}})
```

**Solution**

```
#group by name, thing and then concat belongs
df = df.groupby(by=['Name','Thing'])['belongs']\
               .apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.astype(str).tolist())))\
               .to_frame().reset_index()

df.groupby(by=['Thing','belongs'])['Name']\
          .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.tolist())).to_frame().reset_index()

Out[1140]: 
   Thing belongs      Name
0     10     1,2  John,Tom
1     10       3       Bob
```

Comment: Is it possible to group them by "Thing", so i will have two groups not three?